# How to make php layouts in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, templates, laravel-5

A couple of days ago, I decided to start using laravel for the next project, but I'm confused as I don't find the documentation very compelling and I'm still a laravel beginner .

So, I didn't find a solution for how to create a layout using PHP (and not built in blade templating engine).

How can I do that? What's the best way to organize layouts in a big project?

Thank you

Comment: Why you not prefer blading ?

Comment: I want to use php because I don't want to run through unnecessary compilations. since Blade is compiled to Php, why should I use it, besides I don't intend to work with a frontend engineer  who doesn't know PHP ... So no need for a templating engine.

Comment: For the common layout you will be using `include` or `require` in php Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, I guess so... but aren't their built in functions to load layouts, and extend them ( equivalent to twig or blade's extend) ?

Comment: No, You can say like that. It is not really a recommended practice. Don't think that laravel once again compiles the file. Just think about the features can gain by the blading way. If you understand the possible gains of using blading template. You will never think of those built in functions. (You may prefer blade for simple include if you really understand the plus of using blade ) :)

Comment: So, here it is, I will give it a try with blade ... thank you so much dear friend. I just wanted to know if there's a way to do the same with php, But I made my mind now, I'll do it with blade, thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, there are. Shall I tell some good practice in native php way ?

Comment: Writing answer for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many methodologies that deal with handling templates.

Here are few,

**1. Using a regular `include` or `require`**

You can include the `header.php` , `sidebar.php` and `footer.php` and as many files that you prefer for each sector(It depends on the size of the template)

**2. Using a common file and having classes inside it**

Include a single file and call the classes to render each area

like

```
class Head {
    public function render($_page, $_data) {
        extract($_data);
        include($_page);
    }
}
```

**3. Use a Templating Engine**

```
You shall prefer few templating engine like smart, raintpl etc., (I guess you don't prefer it ;) )
```

**4. Acquiring by inc**

You can include as [suggested here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/159531/121045)

```
<html>
      <head>
         <title><?=$this->title</title>
      </head>
      <body>Hey <?=$this->name?></body>
</html>
```

And the php area would be

```
$view = new Template();
$view->title="Hello World app";
$view->properties['name'] = "Jude";
echo $view->render('hello.inc');
```

**5. By having template segments in db**

Believe me, I saw many good sites which stores the template in the database and it will be rendered each time. It might look like strange idea, but even i tried it for one of my project.

**Conclusion :**

But if i use Laravel, for sure i will prefer the Blading Tempalte Engine and I recommend you the same.

### Update :

Few benefits of Using Blade Templates

**1. Easy Setting of attributes**

Set the attributes on the go

`<title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>`

**2. Easy yielding**

```
   <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
```

**3. Simple echoing**

Like this

```
Hello, {{ $name }}
```

**4. Easy Condition**

Like this

```
{{ isset($name) ? $name : 'Default' }}
```

**5. Never Escape**

Like this

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

**6. Beautiful If Statements**

I prefer this way to make my code more beautiful

```
@if (count($records) === 1)
    I have one record!
@elseif (count($records) > 1)
    I have multiple records!
@else
    I don't have any records!
@endif
```

**7. Checking Authentication**

The simplest way to check the authentication

```
@unless (Auth::check())
    You are not signed in.
@endunless
```

**8. Easy For Loop**

How this for loop looks like

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    The current value is {{ $i }}
@endfor
```

**9. Awesome foreach statement**

Splitting the key and value can't be more easy than this

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

**10. Include the files**

How about `include` file like this

```
@include('view.name')
```

**11. Passing parameters to views**

Can Pass this array to your view

@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])

Source : [Laravel Templates](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates)

Comment: Thank you so much friend, +1 , Best Answer ... I will use blading as you suggested, but it's good to know about these methodologies too.

Comment: However I will add some direct benefits of using blade in few time , which would help future readers ;)

Comment: Thank you so much again, this would be useful reference. Have a fruitful day ;)

Comment: The reason why I want to use laravel : I already started a social network with symfony, but symfony is very heavy, besides it complicates really small tasks... all I need is a small and flexible framework... that's why i start with laravel which is the most popular as I know.

Comment: Cool, then i would recommend you to spend some quality time about the features, best practise of laravel. So, that you can gain the full advantages and benefits of Laravel :)